# Remove dictionary element based on dict.values()

Tags: python, python-2.7

If the string 'email' is not in dict values, I want to delete the corresponding element, so i did the following:

```py
[ my_dict.pop(k) for k , val in my_dict.items() if 'email' not in val ]
```

So any better solution to do that?
Is it better to write a long line of code like above or to do the following:

```py
    for k , val in my_dict.items():
        if 'email' not in val:
            my_dict.pop(k)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use a list comprehension if you're not going to use the list! Similarly, don't use `dict.pop` if you're not going to use the popped value. It's also not a good idea to override builtin names like `dict`. More pythonic would be:

```
for key, val in my_dict.items():
    if 'email' not in val:
        del my_dict[key]
```

Comment: Thanks , yes i know we shall not override builtin names , just i wrote dict here as example , I modified the description now

Answer (score 1):

You are deleting based on an aspect of the value. In my eyes, your approach is not bad, especially if you would be tight on available memory.

Another approach would be a dictionary comprehension, which should be slightly faster but uses more memory since you would be copying over the old dictionary into a new one:

```
my_dict = {key: val for key, val in my_dict.items() if 'email' not in val}
```

As far as I remember, dictionary comprehensions like this have been introduced in Python 2.7. Alternatively, you could also do this:

```
dict = my_dict([(key, val) for key, val in my_dict.items() if 'email' not in val])
```

I would recommend choosing between your current approach and mine based on the expected size of the dictionary and memory restrictions.